# Speed up this for loop in python for custom function on array

Tags: python

I have a for loop that is calculating the sum of the output of a custom function called calculate_some that takes tuples as input and then outputs a single value. I wanted to speed up this code as it goes through 1000+ values.

Can vectorization speed this up ? What are my options ?

```
sum_calculate = 0
for i in  range (0,len(GT_ndarray)):
    sum_calculate = sum_calculate + calculate_some(Candidates[i][0],Candidates[i][1])  

print(sum_calculate)
```

The code for calculate_some is this

```
def calculate_some(arr1,arr2):
    some = arr1[0]*arr2[0]+arr1[1]+arr2[1]+arr1[2]*arr2[2]
    return some
```

Comment: Then try with threads or multiprocessing. Control max threads

Comment: Are the operations in `calculate_some` vectorizable ?

Comment: Maybe use 'pandas.apply()' as I think it is much faster than crude looping

Comment: 1. Can you use `numpy` or `pandas`? 2. In your definition of `calculate_some` you wrote `arr1[1]+arr2[1]`, should this be `arr1[1]*arr2[1]`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `multiprocessing.Pool`, for example

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def worker(i):
    return calculate_some(Candidates[i][0],Candidates[i][1])  

pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count() - 1)
sum_calculate = sum(list(pool.map(worker, range(len(GT_ndarray)))))
pool.close()
```